# get pre-session-id ,but next php file still create a new session

Tags: php, session

*01.php*:

```
  <?php
$savepath="./se/";
$lifetime=10*3600;

session_save_path($savepath);
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();

$_SESSION['name']="aaajjj";
echo "name:".$_SESSION['name']."<br>";

$snid=session_id();
echo "snid:".$snid."<br>";

$url="<a href="."\"002.php?s=".$snid."\">next</a>";
echo $url;

?>
```

*02.php*:

```
<?php

session_id($_GET['s']);
$snid01=session_id();
echo"snid01:".$snid01."<br>";

session_start();

$snid02=session_id();
echo"snid02:".$snid02."<br>";

if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    echo "name:".$_SESSION['name']."<br>";
}else{
    echo"close";
}

    session_destroy();
?>
```

- *01.php* output:

  name:aaajjj 
  snid:aaaaaaaaa
  next
- 02.php output:

  snid01:aaaaaaaaa
  snid02:bbbbbbbbb
  close

  the pre-session-id already get from \next</a>,but 002.php still create a new session.

Comment: and I can echo the session-id of '01.php' in ' 02.php' .

Comment: remove this `session_destroy();` and test

Comment: and I change all code, but there still get a problem.

Comment: ok, before `if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){ ` use this print_r($_SESSION); check what r u getting....

Comment: thanks. but print_r($_SESSION) output this "  Array ( ) ".

Comment: and in 002.php $snid02 shows , session_start() create a new session-id. but i can't find this new session file.

Comment: first of all remove this session_destroy();

Comment: problem is deal with  by add codes   "  $savepath="./se/";  session_save_path($savepath); "

Comment: ok, when u removed `$savepath="./se/";
$lifetime=10*3600;

session_save_path($savepath);
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);`, its work fine?

Comment: 002.php do not know what I set route of session files.  thanks!!!

Comment: ofcourse.. 002.php must know the path

Comment: yes. but I want set a new session file fold.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-save-path.php this will help

Comment: do u know how to include this file ? in 002.php

Comment: please show me a example.

Comment: session_save_path  thanks!

Comment: still working??? not resolved??

Comment: every thing is good.  I just want to know how trans session-id by using a *.php as parameter。

Comment: so no one can see session-id in a browser.